# Porta 80(HTTP Server) e 1935(Mídia Server) não funciona usando VPN

Tags: vpn

Tenho um servidor `HTTP` mas não consigo faze-lo funcionar com uma rede `VPN` publica ativada, sem a rede `VPN` posso acessar normalmente com o meu `IP` real, mas com o `IP` da rede `VPN` não consigo nenhuma conexão com o servidor `HTTP` e o servidor de Mídias.

Existe alguma configuração ou alguma forma de faze-los funcionar com `VPN`?

Comment: Caso a pergunta não se enquadre dentro dos padrões da comunidade, por favor, comentem aqui antes de votarem para fechar ou negativarem, assim eu mesmo a removo.

Comment: para se criar uma tag basta digitar o nome da tag no caso vpn e depois a tecla de espaço.

Comment: Obrigado pelas informações, mas será que eu tenho pontos suficientes? De qualquer forma é bom saber, desconhecia.

Comment: Tem sim o minimo é 300 pontos

Comment: Forida adicone sempre o seguinte frase ao fragmento da definição de tag: Se a dúvida não for sobre o "NOME TAG", não use esta tag, mesmo que esteja usando o "NOME TAG" no seu projeto. sinalize este comentário para que eu o apague